# An expression for law students using "tuppence"

Tags: expressions, british-english, legalese

Has anyone heard of an expression, from the Renaissance or older, containing the word "tuppence" which describes a student of the law or someone without a great deal of experience or training in it?

Comment: I think this is "too localised"

Comment: Actually, it's not localized. The reference to law student is a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

Do you perhaps mean "tuppeny ha'penny"?  It's a general term for something cheap and shoddy.

Comment: There's also the much rarer [don't know tuppence](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=snowily&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22don%27t+know+tuppence%22&pbx=1&oq=%22don%27t+know+tuppence%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=22110l23703l1l24219l6l6l0l0l0l0l187l828l2.4l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=34a0b80f1e2d19ba&biw=1144&bih=857), which one can imagine might be said of an inexperienced lawyer.

Comment: Ah, I haven't heard that for a while or "not worth tuppence".

Comment: Thanks for clearing up some [Elvis Costello imagery](http://www.elviscostello.info/lyrics/ib.html#man_out_of_time) for me!

Answer (score 0):

*Tuppence* is a contraction of sorts for **two pence**, that is, not a lot or practically nothing.

Comment: -1 This doesn't give an expression describing a law student (unless you're saying that tuppence *is* the expression).

Comment: @zpletan Is there a reason this should or should not be applied to law students alone?

Comment: @Kris unless the expression (about anybody, law student or not) runs similar to *he is tuppence*, this does not answer the question. Perhaps I downvoted too hastily; is *tuppence* (or *tuppenny*) the British equivalent of *two-bit*?

Comment: At least you didn't google it first. :-) Maybe you still haven't.

Comment: @Kris, I didn't find much, so I'm guessing that it's not equivalent to *two-bit*. If you or Brad (or anybody) edits in an example usage of *tuppence* as an expression, I'll reverse my downvote.